# Ping from Azure VM to sensor on client PC NIC

Tags: vpn, azure

I have a Azure VM connected to remote PC via Azure-VPN tunnel at NIC1 --  using Azure Vnet technology. My PC NIC2 is connected to a sensor.

I am using windows 7 OS. How am I able to ping the sensor from Azure VM?

====================================================================

[image]

Comment: You'll need to setup routing for the traffic on the remote PC. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/

Comment: For Azure VPN, you could not use route for the traffic to other IP ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean your Sensor PC could not ping NIC1?

If you could, you could set up a [Site-to-Site VPN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal).

If you could not, based on my knowledge, Azure VPN gateway does not support  transitive relationship. You could not ping from Azure VM to Sensor. You could create a Point-to-Site VPN tunnle to Azure from your Sensor PC.

Point-to-Site VPN connection does not need a VPN device or Public IP. Now, you have a VPN gateway on Azure Virtual Network, you could create a connection to Azure. More information about how to create Point-to-Site VPN please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal).

After the VPN connection is established, you could ping from Azure VM to your Sensor PC.

Comment: It should be Site-to-Site VPN. The Azure Point-to-Site VPN is not able or difficult to perform an on-premise access.

I have just figure that out,

Comment: If your Sensor PC is not in your local gateway network, you could not ping it. You need create a new Site-to-Site VPN.

Comment: Thats right. In addition, the remote PC should be Windows Server or some Linux.

Probably desktop windows should be able to do it but it will be more complicated.

Comment: Your Sensor PC? What is the OS type?

Comment: I am using desktop Windows 10.

The Windows Server RRAS will solve the problem, but this is not supported in desktop windows.

Comment: You could use RRAS to create a site-to-site VPN. I test on my lab, it works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58035/discussion-between-tay-wee-wen-and-walter-msft).

Comment: Hi, do you create VPN connection successful? If you have question about it, we could discuss about it.

Comment: If you create it succeeds, don't forget it as an answer.

Comment: Hi Walter, there is a limitation on Site to Site VPN, which requires a public IP address.

Is it possible to use a point-to-site VPN and route the on-premise traffic to Azure?

Comment: No, route on-premise traffic to Azure is not supported.

Comment: You could create a point-to-site VPN on your VM.

Comment: I have sensors which need to use the Windows as a router (bridge) to access the Azure. 

How can it be done without public IP address?

Comment: You could try to use `RRAS` to create a Site-to-Site VPN, it does not require a Public IP.

Comment: BTW the Azure point-to-site VPN creates an adapter on Windows. I am thinking of routing the adapter traffic to the on premise sensors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58370/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-tay-wee-wen).

Comment: Site to Site VPN on Azure does not requires public IP address?

Comment: @TayWeeWen Hi, do you solve this issue now?